# Scope return value - how is that called?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I just discovered this construct, in ObjectiveC (probably works in C as well, I guess):

```
self.versionLabel.text = ({
    NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Version", nil), version];
});
```

Where the value assigned to `versionLabel.text` is the value of the last line of the block.

But this is not really a "block" as we call them in ObjC... Any idea how we name that construct?